# Sandbox for Android App

Tags: support, android-app, testing, sandbox

Testing the android app effectively will have to include exercising all its features, but I don't want to pollute real sites with test data. <s>Could the alpha test app get access to test sites?</s>

---

You can use this question as a formatting sandbox for testing the [android-app](/questions/tagged/android-app)

Comment: Use the [sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) post on Meta, or this post.

Comment: Tagged [meta-tag:sandbox] as per Robert's^ suggestion.

Comment: Who the heck took my Tonka trucks out of my sandbox?

Comment: @AndrewBarber You really take the *sandbox* part seriously :P

Comment: @Asheesh Hey... if you had as much of this stuff in your _shorts_ as I do right now, so would you...

Answer (score 1):

This is at least confining the pollution to one question. Any one else wants to test the up vote question button?

Test edit after update.

*update* edit question again.

Comment: Testing 123. Is this long enough yet.

Answer (score 1):

Testing tag: [android-app](/questions/tagged/android-app)

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

Testing [link](http://www.google.com)

`code`

Keyboard: <kbd>Shift</kbd>

Overflow?  <kbd>sffssdfggcggfffdddfssseffdddffdssffrwwwwwtyuuiooggbnnmmhghhgdfgg f2f hgddftgfdeeewweyyyuuiiiicccxdddsaaaaaa as dtyhhjkkkk</kbd>

list 1

Comment: currently not showing up correctly on mobile

Answer (score 1):

Just a post to do some tests with.

ส้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้      ้

Comment: And comments for the same purpose     ノส้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้    ノส้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ノส้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ノส้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ノส้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้   hm, comments don't seem to refresh after you edit them...้

Comment: Are those characters supposed to be flying off my screen?

Comment: @Diederik  Sorta. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/198044/168660

Comment: Thanks, was thinking it's just me seeing things again!

Comment: Test commenting and such..

Answer (score 1):

Testing how pages opened from links to revision histories look like:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/194835/revisions

It works! The revision history opens in the desktop view even though meta.se itself opens in mobile view:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do community wikis work? Lets find out; can you edit this?

Yes, I can from the Android app.

Comment: I see an edit link on the desktop site, but not in the app. ver 0.1.21

Comment: @Undo Did you edit from the [meta-tag:android-app]?

Comment: No edit link or option on the app. But this [my own] comment is editable.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another test answer. Just testing the UX

Comment: Ignore me, I'm just testing something.

Comment: Just testing comments

Comment: Commenting on this again to uh... test something. yep. Just  testing. Sorry for the notifications Jeremy.

Answer (score 0):

Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz &nsbp

Comment: Hmm, app crashed when submitting that.

Answer (score 0):

Testing posting answer here because Formatting Sandbox is awfully large! Will I get the "An answer has been added" message?

Edit: yes ([Sending an answer shows the new answer message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273876/sending-an-answer-shows-the-new-answer-message) on v1.0.82 beta)

---

Testing deleting post will dismiss notification related to it on PC, but not on app.

Edit: yes ([Notification of comments in deleted posts stay in app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237638/notification-of-comments-in-deleted-posts-stay-in-app) on v1.0.83)

Comment: What's this all about???

Comment: This is a test comment.

Comment: I'm not your test-dummy...