# Android app can't keep comments straight on multiple answers

Tags: bug, comments, android-app

I opened [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/90106/1925) from the hot-feed today in 0.1.27. As I went through the collection of answers, I voted on several and commented on 3 of them. When I got done, I realized none of my comments were showing up. I refreshed the pane and still nothing. I opened the question in a browser and discovered my last comment was actually showing up, but not on the answer I posted it on!

I re-commented from the browser and deleted the bogus comment from the app. Later when I checked back I discovered at least one more of the comments showed up -- this time late as well as on the wrong answer.

Something is short circuiting. Perhaps the fact that this was an active question with votes and comments flowing freely during the time I had it open and the position of answers was changing caused the bork? Whatever the case, I'm sure I selected the comment button from below the correct answers, and just as sure that my comments (of the ones that did show up) turned up on the wrong answers.

Comment: 0.1.28 introduced a new way to add comments for answers. If this is from the old version this may have already been fixed (but it may not have).

Comment: @HodofHod As usual my country's play store is a few hours behind, 0.1.28 hasn't landed yet. Even if it does, I'm not sure how to test this since I don't know exactly what the cause was to duplicate. It could have to do with edits, new answers, votes or other comments happening while I was commenting. This bug report is just a "something broke", not a confirmed "x is broken when y".

Comment: Right. I suppose you could play around in the Android sandbox question to see if you could duplicate it and if you can figure out what exactly causes it. It definitely sounds like the problem is with the app and not with anything on Stack Exchange's side.

Comment: @HodofHod Android sandbox question? Link?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194835/168660