# KBD and Meta-tags are not working in Android-App

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, android-app, kbd

This can be seen [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194835/sandbox-for-android-app#answer-196375) but I've attached a picture as well:

[image]

Comment: To me, the above looks much better... (Also, how are folks using that Android app going to understand what you *expect* it to look like?)

Comment: This is the same as they're [tag:render]ed in comments... it feels like a design decision.

Comment: oh well if someone can confirm it is a design decision and post it as an answer, I'd be more than happy to accept it. IMO I think tags make a difference. Right now they look exactly like hyperlinks and what would stop me from putting a link to an outside source rather than the actual tag itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of the next app update, `<kbd>` stylings will show up correctly.

Tags (and meta tags) showing up as tags are a [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) for the moment.

[image]

Comment: What version is this? I'm not seeing it in 0.1.33

Comment: It'll be in version 0.1.34.