# Notification of comments in deleted posts stay in app

Tags: bug, comments, notifications, android-app

If I dismiss a comment on my computer then the notification also vanishes on my android phone.

But if I get a comment on one of my posts and I delete the post, then the notification vanishes on my computer but stays on my android phone.

At least this is how it looks like.

Comment: Still repro'd on v1.0.83. Also, when you open the app from the notification, the inbox will be updated/synchronize to the server, and related notifications will be gone. (Kind of phantom notification)