# Sending an answer shows the new answer message

Tags: bug, android-app

If you send an answer on Android beta you get the message that a new answer was given to the question alongside with a reload option, even though your answer is displayed.

Comment: Repro'd on SE app v1.0.82 (beta) (just to clarify the exact version)