# How do I access an SE site's sandbox?

Tags: support, sandbox

I have a question I am uncertain about, but I can't find Writing SE's sandbox. I might be blind, but it seems to be in no logical place, because it should be easily accessible due to it being a great tool for new members.

So *where is it* or how do I access it? And please don't redirect me to Writing Meta because this question applies to all sites, since all SE sites have a sandbox.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not all sites have sandboxes. Sandboxes are created by the community when they see a need (and hopefully have the ability to moderate one). See for example the [discussion here on creating a sandbox](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3104/8354).

I can think of a few that have "content review" sandboxes (almost always for questions):

- [Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/66025) (MathJax enabled)
- [Computer Science Educators](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/q/202) (MathJax enabled)
- [Interpersonal Skills](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3129/8354)
- [Islam](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2966)
- [Politics](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5832/)
- [Puzzling](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5276/25084) (MathJax enabled)
- [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9981/22818) (MathJax enabled)

On some sites, people are willing to give feedback in chat or on meta (where you would just post a question with the content of your proposed question, and clearly label it as a request for feedback). For example, this is the policy for [RPG SE](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7373/42375), which has the [workshop-question] tag for this.

If any of these sandboxes has been protected, someone will probably unprotect it if you either flag or ask in chat. It’s also good to note that [some sites allow you to post on their metas at 1 rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160292/323179); Code Golf and Worldbuilding are among them.

---

There are countless others that have formatting sandboxes, but it would be inappropriate to ask for anything (other than maybe formatting help) in those. I might as well make a list of those I know:

- [Anime and Manga](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/857)
- [Arqade](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/716/153006)
- [Chemistry](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3077)
- [Chess](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/q/115)
- [Code Review](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2450/104611)
- [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/434)
- [English Language Learners](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2923/41273)
- [Etherium](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/q/275)
- [French](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/q/152)
- [Gardening & Landscaping](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/q/261)
- [Japanese](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1540)
- Mathematics: [Drafts](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4666), [General](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/370)
- [MathOverflow](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/55)
- Meta SE: [General](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122/323179), [API](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/51812/323179), [Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194835/323179)
- [Movies & TV](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2824)
- [Music Practice and Theory](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2581)
- [Physics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/389)
- [Puzzling](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6052/25084) (not to be confused with the [Riddle Sandbox](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5276/25084) from the first list)
- [Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269754/6083675)
- [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/317)
- Stack Overflow en Español: [General](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1706), [Stack Snippets](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3293)
- [スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/331) (Stack Overflow in Japanese)
- [Super User](https://meta.superuser.com/q/5930)
- [Travel](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3733)
- [Unix & Linux](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/646)

Some of these are dedicated to a specific purpose, such as testing Mathjax (but whether anyone enforces it is another story). On the flip side, remember that [MathJax is only enabled on certain meta sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216607/323179).

Comment: Maybe it is worth mentioning the [SO Mentor program](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357198/mentorship-research-project-results-wrap-up) as that offered a true sandbox for question while it was being worked on in chat between  mentee and mentor

Comment: Indeed. Some sites actively resist having one.