# How can I save drafts for multiple questions on one Stack Exchange site?

Tags: feature-request, questions, draft

I have several questions about Mathematica I am going to ask at the [Mathematica Stack Exchange site](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour). I have one dilemma, which involves the fact that I can only have one saved draft at a time.

Is there a way on the Stack Exchange website to save multiple drafts for questions on one website?

In my case, I have several questions I am working on currently:

- How can I use the right Entity function within the Entity Framework of Mathematica?
- How can I create a word square efficiently?

Is there is a way to suggest the ability to save multiple drafts be added to Stack Exchange if there is no way to save multiple drafts?

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to have more than one saved question draft per site. As a workaround, you can:

- Write all your questions in the same draft, then cut out the extra ones when you post, creating a new draft afterwards.
- Use an external program, which has the advantage of making it unlikely you'll lose your drafts. It makes it harder to format though.
- Use a [sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/316371/323179) (if one is available on the site — Mathematica doesn't seem to have one).

Comment: Not enough for another answer, but you can also put one question as an answer draft... this will come with a host of drawbacks, but it allows two separate drafts.